# Return 4th highest value

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

When I am trying to find fourth highest t2 with query

```
SELECT MAX(T2) 
FROM TST
WHERE T2 NOT IN
(
SELECT DISTINCT T2 
FROM TST 
ORDER BY T2
DESC LIMIT 3
);
```

it shows:
*'This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'*

Can anyone suggest solution to this or an alternate query for same?

Comment: @letronas That's SQL-Server, not MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the subquery. The `LIMIT` keyword can be given a starting offset.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2
FROM TST
ORDER BY t2 DESC
LIMIT 3, 1
```

This means to return 1 row starting at offset 3 (offset is zero-based, so this is the 4th highest).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIMIT` combined with `ORDER BY`.

For example:

```
select t2 from t order by t2 desc limit 3, 1
```

With the data set:

```
create table t (t2 int);

insert into t (t2) values (10), (50), (30), (20), (60), (80);
```

You get the result:

```
t2
--
30
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3ybXf66edMtEnmKNNpzfkw/0).